# Como hacer que GitLab apunte a un directorio en el servidor de desarrollo?

Tags: php, apache, git, gitlab

esta es mi primera pregunta y espero formularla de forma entendible.

Tengo un servidor de desarrollo con Ubuntu + apache + php + mysql en el cual tengo un proyecto desde hace años en la carpeta var/www/html/proyecto1/  al cual accedo por samba desde mi computador en la red local. Edito los programas con Notepad++, grabo, pruebo invocando la IP interna o el DNS dinámico. Si funciona, subo por FTP el programa al servidor de produccion que está en otro país.

En este mismo servidor casero de desarrollo, instalé GitLab que responde perfecto en el puerto 8081.

Hasta ahí todo funciona, pero como soy novato en GIT, no he logrado encontrar informacion de hacer lo siguiente: Necesito que el proyecto que cree en GitLab apunte a la carpeta var/www/html/proyecto1/ y que cuando haga commit/pull via GIT desde mi laptop, se encargue de actualizar los programas PHP de tal modo que una vez que haya testeado que funcionan, los tomo y los subo por FTP al servidor de produccion.

Es posible hacer esto?, como?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Es posible hacer esto? **Si**, como?: [Algunos ejemplos](https://www.google.es/search?q=deploy+git+php)

Comment: gracias por la ayuda.... voy a probar como me va. saludos!